# How to change GTA Online Freemode Events Session Settings?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

The new GTA Online Freemode Events came out this week. In Rockstar's release they say:

> "One of these events can kick off at any given moment while in
>   Freemode, and you can customize your session to decide exactly which
>   ones will happen – so you can play as much or as little of this new
>   content as you like."
>   http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52497/the-gta-online-freemode-events-update-coming-next-week

We had a Closed Crew Session last night and could not find where/ how to customize the session settings.

The Interaction menu now has "Hide Options" and where you can show/hide Map Markers/ Jobs/ Events - but that seems to happen on a personal level.

Any guidance on how to customize Freemode Event session settings in GTA Online would be appreciated.

I've also posted a related question about how to get the Freemode Events happening more regularly: [How to Make GTA Online Freemode Events Happen More Regularly?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236827/how-to-make-gta-online-freemode-events-happen-more-regularly)

Comment: This probably doesn't justify an answer on its own, because the [answer is just what I've stated](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244816/130645) to your [other question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236827/how-to-make-gta-online-freemode-events-happen-more-regularly). Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: Hi @Tas - thanks for that. Feel free to repost the answer. This question has had over 2,000 views so it's a question people are searching for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [my answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/244816/130645) to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236827/how-to-make-gta-online-freemode-events-happen-more-regularly), it is not possible to change the event settings, despite [Rockstar Games saying](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52497/the-gta-online-freemode-events-update-coming-next-week):

> you can customize your session to decide exactly which ones will happen – so you can play as much or as little of this new content as you like

Each player is only able to customise the events that they see, and participation in any event is always voluntary:

> If you’d like to turn off Freemode Event notifications, you can choose to hide it using the Interaction Menu. Select the “Hide Options” feature, then choose “Events”. In this menu, you can choose to hide all Events, or just those you’d rather not see. You can always unhide Events in the same menu.

Events appear every 12 minutes, but note that some events (e.g. Hunt The Beast) require a minimum number of players.

To back all this up, you can check out the [Rockstar Games GTA V FAQ](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/210266807-Freemode-Events-Information-for-GTA-Online-on-PS4-Xbox-One-and-PC) (emphasis mine):

> Freemode Events are launched every 12 minutes from the end of the last Event. On occasions where there are not enough available players in session to launch any Event, launching may take a little longer. Once more players have joined, the Events will continue to launch.
>
> Freemode Events are set up to launch the full variety of Events, so Events do not usually repeat if they’ve been recently played in that session. **Also, different Events require a different minimum number of players before they trigger -- Hunt the Beast requires a minimum of 10 players in session before it can be launched.**
>
> Freemode Events are available in private sessions; however, many Freemode Events require a minimum number of participants in order to begin. Time Trials are not available in private or solo sessions.