# How to Make GTA Online Freemode Events Happen More Regularly?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

Last night we had 7 players in a Closed Crew Session on GTA Online.

Every 15 minutes or more a "Freemode Event" would kick off, and after the event finished we'd need to wait another 15 minutes or more for another Event to be announaced.

As we just wanted to play Freemode Events this essentially turned Freemode into a boring lobby where we found ourselves faffing about waiting for another event to start.

We had limited time to be online as a crew and wanted to concentrate on the Freemode Events as we've all done enough faffing about in Freemode to last a life time.

Is there any way to make the events start more regularly? 5 minutes would be ideal as it would give players just enough time to settle scores and re-equip before getting thrown into another (very fun) Event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do this. Despite [Rockstar Games saying](http://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/52497/the-gta-online-freemode-events-update-coming-next-week):

> you can customize your session to decide exactly which ones will happen – so you can play as much or as little of this new content as you like

I believe they either backed out on that promise because events can award a decent sum of RP + money (I've gotten $13,500 and roughly 2k RP from an event before) or they were simply referring to the ability for each player to customise what events they see:

> If you’d like to turn off Freemode Event notifications, you can choose to hide it using the Interaction Menu. Select the “Hide Options” feature, then choose “Events”. In this menu, you can choose to hide all Events, or just those you’d rather not see. You can always unhide Events in the same menu.

Events appear every 12 minutes, but note that some events (e.g. Hunt The Beast) require a minimum number of players.

To back all this up, you can check out the [Rockstar Games GTA V FAQ](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/en-us/articles/210266807-Freemode-Events-Information-for-GTA-Online-on-PS4-Xbox-One-and-PC):

> Freemode Events are launched every 12 minutes from the end of the last Event. On occasions where there are not enough available players in session to launch any Event, launching may take a little longer. Once more players have joined, the Events will continue to launch.
>
> Freemode Events are set up to launch the full variety of Events, so Events do not usually repeat if they’ve been recently played in that session. **Also, different Events require a different minimum number of players before they trigger -- Hunt the Beast requires a minimum of 10 players in session before it can be launched.**
>
> Freemode Events are available in private sessions; however, many Freemode Events require a minimum number of participants in order to begin. Time Trials are not available in private or solo sessions.